# Installing Go in Linux(Mint) and modifying bashrc

Tags: linux, mercurial, go

I want to install Google's Go Language on my Linux Mint machine. I'm new to Linux so its not easy to follow some of the instructions I have read. Namely, I have been told to edit/mod the bashrc file:

```
 export GOROOT=$HOME/gosource
 export GOARCH=amd64
 export GOOS=linux
 export GOBIN=$HOME/bin
 export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

I don't know how to do this. I typed `gedit ~/.bashrc`

into the terminal and a blank page appeared. I put in the code and saved it. Then did

```
hg clone -u https://go.googlecode.com/hg/ go
```

to get the source code. Is this correct? Because I then tried to compile the code and a long list of errors appeared (which I don't have - I'm using a different PC at the mo unfortunately).

But if anyone can help me install Go, I'd appreciate it.

SOLUTION:

Aside from various problems mentioned and solved in the answers below, I had forgotten to install the following

```
sudo apt-get install bison ed gawk gcc libc6-dev make
```

WHich is mentioned at the top of the golang.com install page.

Comment: This question doesn't involve any actual programming, so it might be better off at unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Robin: The first step in actual programming is getting the compiler to work. Leave the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amongst other things, you tried to clone the repository to `~/go` and edited `~/.bashrc` to point `$GOROOT` to `~/gosource`.

Read the Go [Getting Started](http://golang.org/doc/install.html) instructions carefully. Either copy and paste commands or check what you type very carefully; check input very carefully before you hit enter. For commands, the `$` sign represents the command prompt, don't type it. Remember, Linux is case sensitive and the distinction between `/` and `\` is important. Check the output of commands very carefully; does the ouput make sense. Run diagnostic commands like `env`, `pwd`, `which`, and `uname`. When you see scroll bars in a Stack Overflow answer, scroll through all the code and output.

First, set up `~/.bashrc`.

```
$ gedit ~/.bashrc

export GOROOT=$HOME/go
export GOARCH=amd64
export GOOS=linux
export GOBIN=$GOROOT/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

Close any open terminal windows and then open a new terminal window to check the new `~./bashrc` and other values.

```
$ env | grep '^\(GO\|HOME=\|PATH=\)'
GOBIN=/home/peter/go/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/peter/go/bin
GOARCH=amd64
HOME=/home/peter
GOROOT=/home/peter/go
GOOS=linux
$ cd $GOROOT/src
$ pwd
/home/peter/go/src
$ uname -a
Linux peter 2.6.32-31-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 18:25:51 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Then clone the repository to `$GOROOT` and you will clone to and compile from the same place.

```
$ hg clone -u release https://go.googlecode.com/hg/ $GOROOT
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 8441 changesets with 31916 changes to 4421 files (+1 heads)
updating to branch release-branch.r57
2702 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ cd $GOROOT/src
$ ./all.bash
< SNIP OUTPUT >
ALL TESTS PASSED
---
Installed Go for linux/amd64 in /home/peter/go.
Installed commands in /home/peter/go/bin.
The compiler is 6g.
$ which 6g
/home/peter/go/bin/6g
```

You haven't posted your output, so I can only guess what your problems are.

For example, you say "the directory is Go", it should be "go"; since Linux is case sensitive, "Go" and "go" are different.

If you omit the `$GOROOT` destination from the `hg clone` command or `$GOROOT` is not set, `hg clone` will default to the `hg` directory. For example,

```
$ env | grep '^GOROOT'
GOROOT=
$ hg clone -u release https://go.googlecode.com/hg/ $GOROOT
destination directory: hg
```

Since you have `GOARCH=amd64`, you should be running a 64-bit version of Linux Mint on an `x86_64` processor. What does your `uname -a` output say? You want the `6g` and `6l` programs to compile and link on an `x86_64` processor, which should be in your `$GOBIN` directory, which should be in in your `$PATH`.

```
$ env | grep '^\(GOBIN\|PATH=\)'
GOBIN=/home/peter/go/bin
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/peter/go/bin
$ which 6g
/home/peter/go/bin/6g
```

You should also have seen this by reading the end of your `./all.bash` command output.

```
ALL TESTS PASSED
---
Installed Go for linux/amd64 in /home/peter/go.
Installed commands in /home/peter/go/bin.
The compiler is 6g.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I have problems still. When I try to clone the repository it automatically creates a directory "hg", Go Getting Started says the directory is "Go". I don't know why it creates hg directory. Secondly, cd $GOROOT/src command returns an error saying src doesnt exist.

Comment: also I changed bashrc: GOROOT=$HOME/hg to see if that works. After compiling I dont get any errors but my test.go file wont compile because if I type command 8g(or 6g) test.go the terminal says 8g/6g doesn't exist.

Comment: @JJG: Read my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
gedit /.bashrc
```

you should have typed

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

The fact that you were able to save it(?!) indicates that either you typo'd what you actually typed in your question, or you were running `gedit` as root. You need to run `gedit` as the same user (your user) that will be doing the compiling, to ensure that you edit the right file.

Comment: Yes I mistyped in in the question. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to tweak the environment in the simplest case.

After cloning, do

```
cd go/src
./all.bash
```

to get Go compiled. After compiling you'll be told where it's installed and how to run it. Then you might want to really modify your environment to update the `PATH` variable. But this question is really out of scope of the Go language, so do what [Robin Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495796/robin-green) suggested.

P.S.
The Debian packages for golang have recently been uploaded to unstable (see [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=574371)), so may be it would be a better idea to grab the source package and build a real Debian package(s) from it.

Comment: Don't use the Debian Go packages. Go is improving too rapidly. The Debian bug you referred to was dated 2010.03.15, which means it's referring to an ancient and obsolete version of Go.